# All X are Y. Then Some Y is X?

Tags: semantics, logic

I have the following statement:

All the actors are girls. All the girls are beautiful.

The conclusions are given below:

**Conclusions**:

1)All the actors are beautiful.

2)Some girls are actors.

My text book says that Both (1) and (2) conclusions follow's from the given statement. There is no doubt in (1) conclusion. But how come the second conclusion will become true. If it's become true then it indicates that if a statement is given in form `All X are Y. Then Some Y is X` is true. Is it so?

In what all cases does this contradicts?

Comment: Depends on the logic you are using.  I think this belongs on SE.philosophy.

Comment: so i should close this, and post it in philosophy ?

Comment: It depends. Are you asking the question of what those statements mean in terms of English grammar? If so, the question belongs here. If not, then ask in philosophy.

Comment: I asked the q in terms of english ;0

Comment: The second conclusion (that some girls are actors) only follows from the original statement if there are some actors.  (See my comment to rems's answer.)

Answer (score 1):

In formal logic, ***some*** means "there is at least one".

They even have a formal notation: character "∀"  (inverted "A") means "All"; character "∃" (inverted "E") means "Exist" *(there exists at least one)*.

**∀ actor: Girl(actor)** means "all the actors are girls".

**∃ actor: Girl(actor)** means there is at least one actor such that Girl(actor) is true.

The first statement obviously implies the second one (assuming that there exists at least one actor): if all actors are girls then there is at least one actor who is a girl.

Comment: Not quite.  The first implies the second only if there is at least one actor.  If there are no actors, then any proposition that applies to "all actors" is true, in formal logic.

Comment: @John That's a good point. Updated the answer.

Answer (score -2):

In ordinary English grammar, vacuously true statements are not allowed. They're permissible in formal logic, but in English, they're only used as jokes. You cannot say, "Here's an argument that's persuaded every atheist I've ever met" if you never met an atheist.

There are many examples of English statements that have a different meaning from what you get when you parse the words with formal logic. For example, "My cousin doesn't believe President Obama is doing a good job of running the country". You cannot say this if your cousin is newborn. In ordinary common English, "I don't believe X" usually means "I believe not-X" (absent convincing context suggesting otherwise).

Comment: -1: grammar does not impose what one is allowed to mean with his/her sentences... The sentence about your cousin is *grammatically* correct whether you have a cousin or not, and whatever his age may be. It may be logically flawed, but that is no matter of grammar.

Comment: @nico: Grammar: The whole system and structure of a language or of languages in general, usually taken as consisting of syntax and morphology (including inflections) and sometimes also phonology and semantics.

Comment: exactly. So... logic or truth is not part of grammar. The sentence *Elephants like to spend winter on the Moon.* is grammatically correct.

Comment: It is also grammar that dictates what conceptual relationship that sentence represents. (That is, what must be the case for it to be factually correct.) Since my answer is about what conceptual relationships sentence structures can represent, is it about the rules of grammar.

Comment: Let me explain this another way, since I'm not quite sure I got this out. Meaning is about what concept a word names. Grammar is about which relationships among words are legal and what corresponding relationships with their concepts those words form. In this case, we aren't talking about which concepts any of the words name. The question of what "I don't think X" means isn't about what "I" means or what "don't" means. It's a question about what relationship among the concepts the words made, not which concepts it relates. So it's about grammar, not *word* meaning.

Comment: I understand your point, but I disagree. "I don't think X" does not necessary mean "I think not-X", there is always the option "I don't have an opinion on the subject" or "I think a third different option". Not everything is black-and-white... Anyway I believe logic is a complete separate thing from meaning and from grammar. The sentence I wrote in my previous comment about the elephants is grammatically correct and it is meaningful (is not just a random sequence of words), but it is an untrue statement. That does not make it grammatically uncorrect.

Comment: I agree. It is an untrue statement that is grammatically correct. That you think this disagree with me means that you don't understand my point. Nor have I said that "I don't think X" *necessarily* means "I think not-X". And yes, logic is completely separate from meaning and grammar (though sometimes the precise lines are blurry, but they aren't in this case). Again, that you think this disagrees with me shows that you don't understand my point. I'll try to clarify one more time.

Comment: Consider "I am happy". Word meaning tell us what concept "I" refers to, same for "am" and "happy". Grammar tells us what relationship this sentence reflects between the concepts -- it means that "happy" is a property that "I" "presently have". Grammar is independent of the exact words and their meanings. You can swap "Jeff" for "I", "was" for "am", and "crazy" for "happy". The grammar is still the same -- the sentence still says that "crazy" is a property that "Jeff" "previously had". The meaning is totally different because we swapped the concepts, the grammar is the same, same relationship.